# convert avi to 3gp with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert avi to 3gp, and reduce the size of frames from 800x600 to a smaller size, suitable for mobiles.
What size should I use and where to set it in this command below?
Please give me the new command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -s qvga -b 6438912 -r 16 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 393216 -ar 32000 -ac 1 -y output.3gp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-vf` option to scale your input video respecting the aspect ratio.

```
-vf scale=352:-1
```

will resize any input to a 352 width video and adjust the height to respect the original aspect ratio.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=352:-1 -codec:v libx264 -b:v 6438912 -r 16 -codec:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 393216 -ar 32000 -ac 1 -y output.3gp
```

Comment: Why include `-s` if you are already using `scale`? `-b` is ambiguous: use `-b:v` instead.